# Update personal Quarto Website with command prompt only/task scheduler?

Tags: r, quarto

I have a html document output from a quarto doc code, and just want to run that and publish it daily to my personal quarto website.  I'm new to R and quarto, but have used task scheduler to do things like this in the past.   I was wondering if there is a way to run the R terminal command

```
quarto publish quarto-pub
```

for a quarto web document so that it runs, renders, and publishes through windows command prompt?  I'd like to employ task scheduler to take care of this.

I've searched a bit and only found ways to execute the code in the command prompt... but I already know that command and need help going a bit further.  Hopefully this is simple and I just don't know.

Comment: Though I have not tried this, one idea could be storing the qmd files in a GitHub repository and using GitHub action to do the scheduled update. [This section](https://quarto.org/docs/publishing/github-pages.html#github-action) from Quarto Docs and [this post](https://tarleb.com/posts/quarto-with-gh-pages/) by @tarleb might be helpful.

Comment: Thanks shafee , I appreciate that and I'll follow up with that.